# minimize the text box is very large size in html .It's not responsive

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Product Sub Category</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
   <select class="form-control chzn-select" style="height: 25px; display: none;"        tabindex="-1" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Choose a Country">
    <div class="chosen-container chosen-container-multi chosen-with-drop chosen- container-active" style="width: 888px;" title="">
     <ul class="chosen-choices">
     <li class="search-choice">
     <span>United States</span>
    <a class="search-choice-close" data-option-array-index="0"></a>
  </li>
    <li class="search-field">
      <input class="" type="text" style="width: 25px;" autocomplete="off"  value="Choose a Country" tabindex="4">
  </li>
  </ul>
    <div class="chosen-drop">
    <ul class="chosen-results">
     <li class="result-selected" data-option-array-index="0" style="">United States</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="1" style="">United Kingdom</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="2" style="">Afghanistan</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="3" style="">Albania</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="4" style="">Algeria</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="5" style="">American Samoa</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="6" style="">Andorra</li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

this section code mostly used in my side.Any part erase is not working.This section is not working.so, i am waiting for correction.

Comment: Your html is incorrect. https://jsfiddle.net/taa2z0wz/. Fiddle mark incorrect tags.

Comment: Html Code in this section.I have is not working to text box in this section

Answer (score 0):

Your `select` and `input` tag does not closed.
See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fsyoch4x/) with correct html.

Add `/` at the end:

```
<input class="" type="text" style="width: 25px;" autocomplete="off"  value="Choose a Country" tabindex="4"/>
```

`Select` requires closing tag:

```
<select class="form-control chzn-select" style="height: 25px; display: none;" tabindex="-1" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Choose a Country">  
</select>
```